# Java equivalent of PHP curls instruction

Tags: java, php, curl

I've been tasked to translate an api from php to java. 
The problem is when I have to call to the Api, it uses the curl library, which I don't even know that well in php, and I'm having a hard time finding its equivalent java. 
Looking through other post I saw that most people recommended to use httpConnection, but still I can't figure it out.
any help would be apreciated:

```
        $ch = curl_init( $curlUrl );            
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true););
        if (strtolower($this->httpmethod) == "post") curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
        $this->output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Thank you.

Comment: similar questions were asked already. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025185/setting-curl-parameters-with-java-httpclient or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+curl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard entry point to HTTP requests in Java is `java.net.URL`. From there you can open a connection to the URL.